# Laravel cannot echo softdeletes field error Carbon Data Missing

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I wanna check if the data has been deletes. So i use eloquent like:

```
$check = ModelName::withTrashed()->where("id","=",$id)
->select("id","deleted_at","other_field")
->get();

foreach ($check as $rw) {
echo $rw->id; // it print the id
echo $rw->other_field; //also print the field value
echo $rw->deleted_at; // Error:

//InvalidArgumentException in Carbon.php line 425:
//Data missing
//at Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s.000', '2016-09-19 07:06:56') in Model.php line 2955
}
```

Then i try to dump to see the value:

```
dd($check);
```

The result of deleted_at echo it value like:

```
  #attributes: array:3 [▼
    "id" => 1
    "deleted_at" => "2016-09-19 07:06:56"
```

Comment: laravel version ?

Comment: Have you added the deleted_at to your $dates in your Model?
`protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];`

Comment: yes. I can delete with ->delete(); command. And the date was fill in the field.
The problem is where i wanna to retrive the deleted dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:
In the error message, date format used by Carbon seems to be a bit off. Try to specify it in your model manually:

```
protected $dateFormat = 'Y-m-d H:i:s';
```

I'm leaving the first part of the answer because that might also help someone who stumbles on this topic through search.

---

dd() stops after the first value, which is soft-deleted in your case, so you simply stop execution before the error. If you remove dd, the loop continues until it breaks. So if you wanna check the all the data up until the error, use print_r instead of dd(), so that output would not stop the script.

Now about your exception. The problem is when Carbon encouters a field that is NULL - a record that's not deleted. It tries to parse null into a date and obviously fails.

Your approach should be changed - you could check if the record is soft deleted before trying to access it's deleted_at timestamp:

```
$check = ModelName::withTrashed()->where("id","=",$id)
  ->select("id","deleted_at","other_field")
  ->get();

foreach ($check as $rw) {
  echo $rw->id; // it print the id
  echo $rw->other_field; //also print the field value

  if ($rw->trashed())
    echo $rw->deleted_at;
}
```

Another, less elegant solution would be to remove deleted_at from $dates array in model and stop the automatic parsing. Then you would write a custom accessor in your model:

```
public function getDeletedAtAttribute($value)
{
    return $value ? Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $value) : NULL;
}
```

I would recommend the first approach.

Comment: Make sure your model is using SoftDeletes trait. Make sure migrations are using $table->softDeletes(); to create fields in database. Is that right?

Comment: No luck. Still have the same error. Tried with trashed method. 
Actually only one record will be in the array because of the id conditions.

Comment: If thats only one record, you should use ->first() instead of ->get() and avoid foreach loop altogether - it will return a collection object immediately.

Comment: Yes Tadas Paplauskas, i use the softDeletes trait adn add $table->softDeletes() in the schema builder. When i use db::raw it return the data deleted_at without error.

Comment: Already tried with first in the first place, Tadas Paplauskas. Still have the same error.

Comment: Please check if you have a getDates() method in your model? It could be overriding the Eloquent method.

Comment: In the error message, date format used by carbon seems to be a bit off. Try to specify it in your model:
protected $dateFormat = 'Y-m-d H:i:s';

Comment: My model.
namespace App\Model;                                                                                                                                                      
 
 use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
 use SoftDeletes;

 class ModelName extends Model
 {
     use SoftDeletes;
 
     protected $table = 'table_name';
     protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
 
 }

Comment: Thanks Tadas Paplauskas. did not see that. That the problem. But why? You can post the answer. I will mark it as answered.

Comment: No idea :). Laravel should use Y-m-d H:i:s by default. Try to composer update, maybe there's some old code in Carbon not playing well together. Updated the original answer, please mark it as accepted and good luck :)